# Issues with Hacker Rank Matrix-Script

Tags: python

my output is exactly the same as the expected output I still get 'Wrong Answer :('
what is the problem with my code?

the input format is
7 3
Tsi
h%x
i #
sM
$a
#t%
ir!

the answer I got is
**This is Matrix#  %!**
and the expected output is
**This is Matrix#  %!**

```
import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys




first_multiple_input = input().rstrip().split()

n = int(first_multiple_input[0])

m = int(first_multiple_input[1])

matrix = []

for _ in range(n):
    matrix_item = input()
    matrix.append(matrix_item)

#my answer starts from here

l =[]
for i in range(0,m):
    s  = ''
    for j in matrix:
        s += j[i]
    l.append(s)
ans = ''
for k in l:
    ans+=k

def islast(m):
    for n in range(m,len(ans)):
        if ans[n].isalpha():
            return False
    return True


l1 = []
temp = ''
for m in range(0,len(ans)):
    if ans[m].isalpha():
        temp+=ans[m]
    elif islast(m) :
        temp = temp + ans[m:]
        l1.append(temp)
        break
    else:
        l1.append(temp)
        temp = ''
finalans = ''
for o in l1:
    if o!='':
        finalans = finalans + " " + o
 
print(finalans.lstrip())
```

Comment: I believe that challenge requested to avoid using `if`s

Comment: my bad I forgot to notice that, Thank you so much